# Idiom for "I thought about it a lot"

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrases, synonyms

I am wondering what are the alternatives for "I thought a lot about it" in English using an idiom or fixed expression?

- **I thought a lot about it,** but I couldn't find any answer to it.
- **I thought a lot about why my tone of voice changes while I switch across languages,** but I couldn't come up with any answer to the question.

Comment: "why my tone of voice changes while I switch across languages" really like to know the answer of this!

Comment: So this is explicitly not a single-word request? You'll only *contemplate* idioms or fixed expressions?

Comment: I don't know if your "question within a question" really is something that (still) puzzles you, but I remember being told that to make my spoken *French* sound more like a native Francophone, I should make a conscious effort to tighten my stomach muscles when speaking. Which would tend to affect my "tone of voice", obviously.

Comment: *I **worried at the problem** for ages, but couldn't come up with a satisfactory answer*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [**gave it a lot of thought**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+some+thought+to) is the first one that occurs to me.

Comment: Can we say: "I gave it a lot of thought" means the same as "I pondered it" @stangdon?

Comment: @A-friend To me, *ponder* is a more formal word, and also means something like "thought about it *deeply*", while "gave it a lot of thought" could just mean "thought about it for a long time."

Answer (score 0):

We could consider *ponder*.

Definition [C2](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ponder) explains.

> to think carefully about something, especially for a noticeable length of time
>
> She sat back for a minute to ponder her next move in the game.

We could hence say

> I ponder it, but I couldn't find any answer to it.

> I ponder why my tone of voice changes while I switch across languages, but I couldn't come up with any answer to the question.